# how can i display items when we click imageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm struggling to use ImageView as a button that I need when I click it should display items,  like when we click a spinner the same procedure.

```
final View imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
 imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
            // display a list of suggestions !
        }
    });
```

I will be thankful if there is anyone who gonna help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can probably use Pop up menu items

Comment: do you have an app in mind or have you seen this behaviour somewhere so we can understand exactly what you need? You seem to have asked teh same question 3 times now, yet no one is really sure what exactly it is you're after.

Comment: yeaah , i m currently working on it. the behaviour is simple when u click the dropdown imageview u display the data that u fetch from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create your menu of items you want to show like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
android:id="@+id/first"
android:title="First Menu Item"/>

<item
android:id="@+id/second"
android:title="Second Menu Item"/>

<item
android:id="@+id/third"
android:title="Third Menu Item"/>

</menu>
```

Then in your Activity you create a `PopupMenu`

```
PopupMenu pm = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, pBtn);
    pm.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, pm.getMenu());
    pm.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.first:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked First Menu Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.second:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Second Menu Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.third:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Third Menu Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    pm.show();
```

Finally you call this `popup menu` in your click listener

EDIT:

Create an ArrayList of String for example

```
ArrayList<String> popupItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Fill your arraylist with your data

Then you initialize your popupmenu with this array list

```
popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, imageButton);
```

Loop through your array add values to the popupmenu menu

```
for (int i =0; i < popupItems.size(); i++)
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, popupItems.get(i))
```

Comment: thank u @Amine ,but the data fetched from the server we don t have a static data ?

Comment: Brother ,now i don t need to create menu.xml file

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to achieve?, do you mean a menu.xml and you add your values to it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the items in dialog, when you click on image view show the dialog